# Dell Management Packs in System Center Operations Manager 2007 R2?

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, scom, dell-openmanage

I recently set up SCOM in a small business network environment. The root management server is a Dell Poweredge 2950, and I'd like to use SCOM to monitor it using Dell's management packs. I've imported the management packs into the SCOM deployment and followed Dell's  installation instructions, but it doesn't seem to be fully working yet.

Currently, the Diagram views in the Dell tree (Monitoring tab) seem to show me the server's place in the network topology, so it seems that at least part of it is working.

However, none of the reports under "Performance and Power Monitoring Views" provide any information. When clicking on one of them (Power Consumption (Watts), for instance), the display area is blank and there is a tooltip visible that reads "No performance counter is selected. To select a counter, place a check mark in the Show column in legend below." However, in the legend, there's nothing there for me to check.

I've installed OpenManage 6.2 on the server as per the Dell documentation, but I don't know what else I could have done that I missed. Does this sound like a familiar problem to anyone?

Comment: Hah. I'm getting the same symptoms when attempting to view the Memory Usage Performance view, and upon googling the symptom I come upon my own un-answered thread from almost three months ago. How sad.

Comment: Do the servers you are trying to get the Power Consumption from actually provide the information at all? We had a similar problem with HP Servers and discovered that only ones purchased in the last 2-3 years actually provided this capability.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, these performance collection rules are disabled by default. You just need to turn them on. From the Dell MP documentation:

> In the Operations Console, Dell→ Performance and Power Monitoring
> Views displays the performance information that is collected from Dell
> Systems. This feature is available on installation of Scalable Server
> Management Pack. By default this feature is disabled. To enable this feature
> perform the following:
>
> 1 Open the Authoring pane in the Operations Console.
>
> 2 Select Rules.
>
> 3 Right-click the rule you want to enable.
>
> For example, to enable information to be collected on energy consumption
> of Dell Systems, select Dell Server Energy Consumption collection rule.
>
> 4 Select Overrides → Override the rule → For all objects of class
>
> 5 Select Override and provide Override value as True.
>
> 6 Click Apply.